# No directory is created for Files in form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file-upload

I have a form to send a message to other users. When sending an attachment directory is not created to save.

**Error**

```
Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\_sesiones\validar.php on line 199

Warning: move_uploaded_file(nicogaldo/adjunto_msj/para_11/2014-09-17/mensajeria.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\_sesiones\validar.php on line 206

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php120F.tmp' to 'nicogaldo/adjunto_msj/para_11/2014-09-17/mensajeria.php' in C:\xampp\htdocs\_sesiones\validar.php on line 206

nombre del archivo: nicogaldo/adjunto_msj/para_11/2014-09-17/mensajeria.php
nombre de usuario: nicogaldo
```

This is the validation of the file to upload:

**PHP:**

```
$Mensaje_msj="";    
$fecha= date("Y-m-d");     
$TamanioMaximo_msj=3000000;    

$CarpetaAlojamiento_msj='../updates_msj/'.$_SESSION['user'].'/para_'.$_POST['user'].'/'.$fecha';

//$CarpetaAlojamiento_msj=$_SESSION['user']; //Works fine :S

$NombreArchivoFinal_msj="";       

  if (!empty($_FILES['adjunto'])) {
    if($_FILES['adjunto']['size']>$TamanioMaximo) {
      $Mensaje_msj.= 'El adjunto debe pesar menos de 3mb';
    } else {

      if (!is_dir($CarpetaAlojamiento_msj)) {
        mkdir($CarpetaAlojamiento_msj);           #line 199
        chmod($CarpetaAlojamiento_msj, 0777);
      }
    }

    $NombreArchivoFinal_msj="$CarpetaAlojamiento_msj/{$_FILES['adjunto']['name']}";

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['adjunto']['tmp_name'])) {     #line 206
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['adjunto']['tmp_name'], $NombreArchivoFinal_msj);
    }

    echo "nombre del archivo: ".$NombreArchivoFinal_msj;
    echo "nombre de usuario: ".$_SESSION['user'];

  }
```

But when I leave `$CarpetaAlojamiento_msj=$_SESSION['user'];` works well.

Any idea?

Comment: you can try `mkdir($CarpetaAlojamiento_msj, 0777, true);`

Comment: why you assign a dir to `$CarpetaAlojamiento_msj`, then assign `$_SESSION['user'] to it again?

Comment: What line? @worldask

Comment: line 199, line of mkdir

Comment: try with `mkdir($CarpetaAlojamiento_msj, 0777, true);` and it works!. 
Is a messaging system between users, `$ _SESSION ['user']` is the logged user. It creates a folder with that name to be more organized

Comment: BTW, you can remove line 200 now, because the directory was already 0777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `mkdir($CarpetaAlojamiento_msj, 0777, true);`, `true` parameter means mkdir recursively.